# Can an iPhone app hide/launch other apps?

Tags: iphone

I am asking this question mainly to know if what I want to do is possible. I don't think there is an app that does it and I've been meaning to learn objective C, but it may not be possible.

I want an app that serves as the ONLY way (at least, the only easy way) to launch another app. So in an ideal world, you have MyApp, which lists app A, B, and C. A B and C are not visible on the normal browser, but can be launched from within my app.

Possible? Not?

Comment: Apple actually prevents it; it keeps apps from launching potentially malicious code or undesired applications.

Comment: You can, however, create the illusion of such a thing by putting the code for the other app within your holder app. The sub app wouldn't actually be an application on the user's iDevice, but it would be usable.

Comment: The goal is not to launch malicious code, per se, but rather to hide apps that you wouldn't want your mom to see on your phone, for example.

Comment: It may be possible to hide an apps icon from view, but not using another app to do so, which iOS doesn't allow  But that is a question for another forum.  Ask there.

Comment: Step one jailbreak your phone, step two download Poof from Cydia store and use it to hide apps. Done. Or tell your mum to GTFO!

Comment: You cannot hides apps in iOS officially. Folders are your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. And its most likely that such a functionality will never make it into the official SDK.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do isn't really possible. It isn't possible (with the official development kit) to create iOS applications that don't appear on the home screen.

It is possible to launch other applications, though -- one common approach is to set them as URL handlers for private URL schemes. This can be used to pass information between applications. (However, trying to use this as access control won't work, because Apple will likely reject an application which can only be opened "correctly" by another app.)

Comment: Darn. It would be nice if any person using your iPhone couldn't see every app you have, but I guess thems the breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of App.

You can just have a master app which creates the illusion of being an app launcher by "opening" subroutines. Imagine like the old facebook iphone app for example

Answer (score 0):

## NO

Well... This has been done for years on the Cydia store with some custom menus but we wont get into that here...

Using the official SDK I think there are protocols to allow you to open an another application but pressing the home button for example will always go back to the default screen. I think ever if you were able to get it working, there is no chance it would be accepted into the App Store on grounds of it not doing anything the phone already does.

By all means look up jailbreaking and using the custom tool chain but you won't be able to sell this through Apple unfortunatley.