# How to launch an app inside an application

Tags: objective-c, c, ipad

I may be blamed of duplicating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907901/can-an-iphone-app-hide-launch-other-apps) or even any of [these](https://www.google.com.tr/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=launch+app+from+app+ios) but really no one answers my issue. I need to launch an app by clicking on a button on my UI, but the application i want to launch has no custom [URL Scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) and here my nightmare gets started. I tried to call the app(using NSBundle-path) ect but i could see no way to call that app. Thanks in advance for any answer-even idea.

**Question-2)** Is there a registery-like system on iOS system? For example, can we add the path of raw apk into a registery and forse it to start? I have a background of C, i can try on myself if it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways to open an app from your app on iOS:

- URL schemes
- Using the UIDocumentInteractionController to allow the user to open a file in another app
- Using private API's

Simple. No there is no registry like system on iOS.

Comment: The kind that Apple would reject your app. Are you ok with that?

Comment: yes i'm. now the only matter is solving the issue. or how to use UIDocumentInteractionController? i dont want to navite till there, when i clicked i want to launch that app

Comment: there is no limit. i may be rejected too no problem

Comment: About UIDocumentInteractionController you should look it up or make another question. About the private API's just give a moment.

Comment: By now I know that you can use the private call SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier from the SpringBoardServices private framework and that you have to give it the entitlement com.apple.springboard.launchapplications but I've been unable to do that last part. I'll look at it later. Open another question more specific.

Comment: i dont have such technical background so i cant ask such a question for the moment. can you please guide me a little more-i can write my mail here and you can send by mail too if you can

Comment: I asked a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204785/special-api-to-launch-an-app-from-my-application). Can you please take a look at

Comment: @the march of the black queen any success?

Comment: @DeepikaLalra yes, URL schemes was the only legal and developer-friendly way for me.